# Mini PC (like Gigabyte BRIX) with more than 2 graphic ports

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, mini-pc

I'm using a Gigabyte BRIX Mini PC running Linux as a viewer for a NoMachine setup with 2 monitors presently, one connected via VGA and one via HDMI.

I am planning on adding a third monitor, which is why I am looking for a small PC, similar to the BRIX, but with three (ideally 4, as a spare) VGA/HDMI ports.

Connecting a USB-VGA adapter like the [products from Plugable](http://plugable.com/2014/03/06/displaylink-usb-2-0-graphics-adapters-on-linux-2014-edition) doesn't seem feasible to me with the lack of true support of these devices under Linux.

Has anybody come across a Mini-PC with more than 2 video ports onboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything with DisplayPort 1.2 or better, eg Intel NUC NUC6i5SYH or NUC6i3SYK.

[DisplayPort daisy-chaining](http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/) allows for up to 5 monitors connected to a single DP socket.

Comment: IIUC these 5 monitors will all display the same thing, right?

Comment: @Stefan No, of course not. If they would be displaying same thing, then they would use same bandwidth so there would be no limit and one might chain unlimited number of displays. DisplayPort v1.2 daisy-chained monitors appear as individual screens.

Comment: Hmm...  but then do all graphics card with a display port output really have at least 5 CRTCs?

Comment: @Stefan I believe so. But DP 1.2 is quite new and there is still plenty of hw with 1.1. And you still need 5 monitors that support DP-out. Eg Dell U2412M doesn't have DP out, but U2414M does.